# When querying a collection using linq it always returns a null

Tags: c#, linq, collections

When querying a collection using linq it always returns a null

```
Collection<JCTransLabour> oJCTransLabours = null;

oJCTransLabour = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"] as 
                                  Collection<JCTransLabour>;

// at this point the collection oJCTransLabours contains 3500 records

var oCurrentLabourTrans = from clt in oJCTransLabours
                          where clt.TransactionDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date
                          select clt;

// at this point the collection oJCTransLabour = null
// I have tried to search on different fields 

return oCurrentLabourTrans;
```

There must be something I am doing wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: After the first step, is the variable oJCTransLabour really not null, or is it HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"] that is not null, because the 'as Collection' operator in c# returns null if the type doesn't match, as opposed to (Collection)variable, which gives an exception.

Comment: As a side note, be careful with `DateTime.Now`. Check out `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least one typo in your question.
You state that after

```
oJCTransLabour = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"] as Collection<JCTransLabour>;
```

`oJCTransLabour` is not null, right? This makes sense if session contains it.

Then you define `oCurrentLabourTrans` and assign LINQ query to it. And then you say that

```
// at this point the collection oJCTransLabour = null
```

Wait, how can it be null? You didn't even modify it (it was `oCurrentLabourTrans` modified) and you just said `oJCTransLabour` is not null!

**Update:** I just noticed there's type in names too: you call it `oJCTransLabours`, then you call it `oJCTransLabour`. Please post the *exact* code so we don't make assumptions about what exactly you might've mistyped.

And, of course, LINQ expression can't be null.
I think it is most likely that `oJCTransLabours` is null though you state the otherwise.

The reason you think so, perhaps, is because you're sure `HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"]` is not null. This is true, but you use `as` operator to cast the value to `Collection<JCTransLabour>`. As opposed to casting operator, `as` doesn't throw an exception if types mismatch, it just returns `null`.

You might want to try

```
oJCTransLabour = (Collection<JCTransLabour>)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"];
```

and see if any errors show up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just confusing variable names:

```
// You were missing an 's' before
oJCTransLabours = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"] 
                                    as Collection<JCTransLabour>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a linq issue, but rather that the value in the session is either null or not a `Collection<JCTransLabour>`.

You could ensure it is not null by changing the lookup to:

```
oJCTransLabour = (HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"] as Collection<JCTransLabour>) ?? new Collection<JCTransLabour>();
```

If there should always be a session value then you could throw an exception if the value was not found before doing the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var oCurrentLabourTrans = (from clt in oJCTransLabours where clt.TransactionDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date select clt).ToList();
```