# When querying a collection using linq it always returns a null

Tags: c#, linq, object

I posted up part of some code the other day but in doing so caused more confusion. This is my code.

```
if ( HttpContext.Current.Session != null )
{
                if ( HttpContext.Current.Session[ "CurrentLabourTransactions" ] != null )
                {
                    Collection<JCTransLabour> oJCTransLabours = null;

                    oJCTransLabours = (Collection<JCTransLabour>)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentLabourTransactions"];

                    if (Settings.ShowTodaysTransactionInApproval)
                        if (oJCTransLabours != null) return oJCTransLabours;


                    if (oJCTransLabours != null)
                    {
//oJCtransLabour contains alot of record
                        var oCurrentLabourTrans = (from clt in oJCTransLabours
                                                   where clt.TransactionDate.Date != DateTime.UtcNow
                                                   select clt);
//oCurrentLabourTrans is null.
                        return oCurrentLabourTrans as Collection<JCTransLabour>;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
```

When going into the final if statement there are a lot of transactions with different dates. It seems to although it always returns null records.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean it always returns *null*, or it always returns a collection of empty rows?

Comment: is 'oCurrentLabourTrans' null or 'oCurrentLabourTrans as Collection<JCTransLabour>' null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When querying a collection using linq it always returns a null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831490/when-querying-a-collection-using-linq-it-always-returns-a-null)

Comment: Have you tested this with a debugger?  Is the collection object populated with data?  It's difficult to say what the problem is without knowing more about your datasource and what troubleshooting steps you have already taken.

Comment: So which line is returning nulls? is it the line after the comment `oJCtransLabour contains alot of record`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
return oCurrentLabourTrans as Collection<JCTransLabour>;
```

`oCurrentLabourTrans` is *not* a `Collection<JCTransLabour>`, and thus the `as` operation returns null, as expected. If you were to do this instead:

```
return (Collection<JBTransLabour) oCurrentLabourTrans;
```

the cast would fail and an `InvalidCastException` would be thrown. LINQ operators produce objects which implement `IEnumerable<>` directly; they do not automatically create collection and list objects.

If you have to return a `Collection<>`, you can do this instead:

```
return new Collection<JCTransLabour>(oCurrentLabourTrans.ToList());
```

Comment: On a side note, if you do this a lot you can create a custom extension that converts to a Collection<>